# Cantor-like construction

Tags: real-analysis

Construct a subset of [0,1] in the same manner as the Cantor set by removing from each remaining interval a subinterval of relative length $\theta$, $0<\theta <1$.

This is the first statement in a homework exercise. I don't know if my English parsing skills are lacking today or what, but it's unclear to me what this means. I just need help understanding what this construction "looks like."

Comment: You may want to take a look at the construction in the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Construction_of_the_ternary_set If I read the question correctly, they want you to follow this same procedure but with an arbitrary length and presumably obtain a similar expression for C like at the end of the section of the article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The construction of the Cantor set begins with the removal of the interval $[1/3,2/3]$, an interval of length $1/3$.  The remaining intervals have length $1/3$; you remove intervals of length $1/9$ from each of them.  At stage $k$, you're removing $2^{k-1}$ intervals of length $1/3^k$.  The total length removed is then $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2^{k-1}}{3^k}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{3}}=1$$
so the Cantor set has measure zero.

Now let $\theta\ne 1/3$.  You can repeat the same construction with $\theta$ instead of $1/3$: at step $k$, you remove $2^{k-1}$ intervals of length $\theta^k$.  This is going to look very much like the Cantor set -- in particular, it has empty interior, which you can prove.  If your homework problem is going where I'm guessing it's going, you should calculate the measure of the set you get for different $\theta$.  Actually, you should do that no matter what the homework says.  The results are quite surprising.

Comment: At stage 1 you remove 1=2^0 intervals! Then your sum is really equal to 1 which is false right now.

Comment: I meant $2^{k-1}$ instead of $2^k$.  Edited to fix.  The sum I had is actually the right one, though.